# Calculate $P(A_n)$, where $P$ uniform distribution on $[0,1]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

$P$ uniform distribution on $[0,1]$. 
$$A_n=\bigcup_{i=1}^{2^n-1} \left [ \frac{2i-1}{2^n}, \frac{2i}{2^n} \right ], n \in \mathbb{N}$$

To calculate $P(A_n)$ do we have to do the following??

$$P(A_n)=P \left ( \bigcup_{i=1}^{2^n-1} \left [ \frac{2i-1}{2^n}, \frac{2i}{2^n} \right ] \right )=\sum_{i=1}^{2^n-1}P\left ( \left [ \frac{2i-1}{2^n}, \frac{2i}{2^n} \right ] \right )=\sum_{i=1}^{2^n-1} \left ( \frac{2i}{2^n}-\frac{2i-1}{2^n} \right )=\sum_{i=1}^{2^n-1}  \frac{1}{2^n} =\frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{i=1}^{2^n-1} 1=\frac{2^n-1}{2^n}$$

Is this correct?? Or is it as followed??

$$P(A_n)=P \left ( \bigcup_{i=1}^{2^n-1} \left [ \frac{2i-1}{2^n}, \frac{2i}{2^n} \right ] \right )=\sum_{i=1}^{2^n-1}P\left ( \left [ \frac{2i-1}{2^n}, \frac{2i}{2^n} \right ] \right )=\sum_{i=1}^{2^n-1} \frac{1}{\frac{2i}{2^n}-\frac{2i-1}{2^n}}=\sum_{i=1}^{2^n-1} 2^n=2^n(2^n-1)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first calculation is correct. Note that

$$\sum_{i=1}^{2^n-1}P\left ( \left [ \frac{2i-1}{2^n}, \frac{2i}{2^n} \right ] \right )=\sum_{i=1}^{2^n-1} \frac{1}{\frac{2i}{2^n}-\frac{2i-1}{2^n}}$$

does not hold; that's where your second calculation fails.

**Remark:** You can simplifiy the calculation by noting that

$$A_n = \left[ \frac{1}{2^n}, 1 \right].$$

Comment: Ok!! Thank you very much!!! :-) 
$$$$
I was confused whether the formula is $P([a,b])=b-a$ or $P([a,b])=\frac{1}{b-a}$...

Comment: @MaryStar By definition it's $P([a,b]) = b-a$. One way to check it: $P$ is a probability measure, in particular $P([a,b]) \leq 1$ for all $a \leq b$. Obviously, this does not hold true for $\frac{1}{b-a}$.

Comment: I see... Thank you!!! :-)